# React JSX code not compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering in the browser an HTML page which references a react class.
Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

On the third line of the following function (the `<div>` statement).

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Res</h1>
        <resE data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
```

It appears that the JSX is not transformed properly.
However, I am referencing JSXTransformer in the HTML file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
```

Furthermore, I tried adding the following line at the top of the file containing the react class:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
```

However, the error persisted.

Answer (score 3):

Can you show the script that your code sits in?

I believe your issue is that you need to make sure that script has the attribute

```
type="text/jsx"
```

so to solve your issue do this;

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="app/restrictions/Main.js"></script>
```

Your JSX compiler script looks for any scripts that have that text/jsx attribute to know that it needs to turn that JSX code to raw JavaScript.

Comment: The script is referenced within the tag.
`<script src="app/restrictions/Main.js"></script>/`
Where should I place `type="text/jsx"` ?

Comment: Thank you. However, when I do that I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` on the first line from the file: `var ResE = require('./ResC');`. I think modyfing the line you indicated breaks something else.

Comment: I would have to see what you're entire page looks like to comment on that, but I can say that is an unrelated issue to the question I answered.

Comment: it is not related to the question being ask, however to answer that, 'require' is not js function. To be able to use require you might want to use something like browserify . http://browserify.org/